# Como eliminar uma Dialog do processo de gravação de dados

Tags: php, jquery

Possuo um sistema legado de controle de cadastro e o mesmo está funcionando perfeitamente no que se diz respeito a gravação dos dados em banco, mas estou tentando adaptar o mesmo e não estou conseguindo.
O script atual mostra uma `dialog` a mais, preciso somente mostrar somente a `dialog` que informa se o registro foi inserido com sucesso ou se ocorreu algum erro, gostaria de eliminar a primeira que é apresentada.

Estou usando esse projeto:[Bootstrap 3 Dialog](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog)

Já tenho isso:

```
    function DlgInserirFase() {
    //Dialog de inserção de dados   

    BootstrapDialog.show({
        //title: 'Fase',
        // message: $('<div id="divNotas"></div>').load('frmMural.html'),
        closable: false,

        buttons: [{

            //icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
            //label: 'Gravar',
            //cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            //autospin: true,

            action: function(dialogRef){

                //Chama o validate do formulário
                // $('#frmFase').validate();
                //if ($('#frmFase').valid() == true) {
                    //dialogRef.enableButtons(false);
                    // dialogRef.setClosable(false);

                    var params = {
                        Operacao:   'Inserir',
                        dTipoFase:  $('#dTipoFase').val(),
                        dData:      $('#dData').val(),
                        dHora:      $('#dHora').val(),
                        dDescricao: $('#dDescricao').val(),
                        IdContrato: $("input[name=IdContrato]").val(),                          
                    };

                    // GravaFase(params);

                    $.post(
                        'ProcessoFase.php',
                        params,
                        function( json, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                            if (json.status != "ERRO") {
                                var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                                    title: 'SUCESSO',
                                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
                                    message: json.msg,
                                    closable: false,
                                    buttons: [
                                        {
                                            label: 'Fechar',
                                            cssClass: 'btn-success',
                                            action: function(dialogRef){
                                                dialogRef.close();
                                                location.reload();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]   
                                }); 
                            } else {    

                                var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                                    title: 'ERRO',
                                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                    message: json.msg,
                                    closable: false,
                                    buttons: [
                                        {
                                            label: 'Fechar',
                                            cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                                            action: function(dialogRef){
                                                dialogRef.close();
                                                // location.reload();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]                                       
                                }); 
                            }
                        },
                        'json'
                    )
                    .fail(function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        try {
                            var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                                title: 'ERRO',
                                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                message: json.msg
                            }); 
                        } catch(e) { 
                            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                                title: 'ERRO',
                                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                message: json.msg
                            }); 
                        }
                    });

                    dialogRef.close();
                //}
            }
        },

        {
            label: 'Cancelar',
            cssClass: 'btn-danger',
            action: function(dialogRef){
                dialogRef.close();
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver, estava co problemas no meu `console.log` e não conseguia ver as mensagens de erro, resolvi esse problema e com um passo-a-passo alterei a forma como estava sendo feito o cadastro, ficou assim:

```
    function DlgInserirFase() {
    //Dialog de inserção de dados   
    var params = {
        Operacao:   'Inserir',
        dTipoFase:  $('#dTipoFase').val(),
        dData:      $('#dData').val(),
        dHora:      $('#dHora').val(),
        dDescricao: $('#dDescricao').val(),
        IdContrato: $("input[name=IdContrato]").val(),                          
    };

    // GravaFase(params);

    $.post(
        'ProcessoFase.php',
        params,
        function( json, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            if (json.status != "ERRO") {
                var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'SUCESSO',
                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
                    message: json.msg,
                    closable: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'Fechar',
                            cssClass: 'btn-success',
                            action: function(dialogRef){
                                dialogRef.close();
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    ]   
                }); 
            } else {    

                var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'ERRO',
                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                    message: json.msg,
                    closable: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'Fechar',
                            cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                            action: function(dialogRef){
                                dialogRef.close();
                                // location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    ]                                       
                }); 
            }
        },
        'json'
    )
    .fail(function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        try {
            var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'ERRO',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                message: json.msg
            }); 
        } catch(e) { 
            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'ERRO',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                message: json.msg
            }); 
        }
    });



}
```